# Google Sheets, formula or script to make selection in a dropdown list based on an existing selection in another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Newb with apps script in Google Sheets here.....

I have two columns each containing different drops down lists. I'd like a formula to change the selection in all cells containing the second drop down list depending on which selection has *already* been made in the first list (I had a script suggested by Chat GPT working if it was run "onEdit" but none that I've tried will work on an entire sheet where the value for the first drop down has already been selected)

Code that worked with onEdit:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
var editedRow = range.getRow();

if (editedColumn == 6) { // Assuming Column F is column 6
if (sheet.getRange(editedRow, 6).getValue() == "Open") {
sheet.getRange(editedRow, 7).setValue("Unassigned"); // Set value in Column G
}
}
}
```

So if "Open" has already been selected in the list in column F, "Unassigned" is selected in the drop down list in column G. Value range in the drop down list in column G is Rochester, Utrecht, Cumbria, Unassigned. If the rule is not met I'd like the selection in column G to remain unchanged. How do I do this  please ?

Chat GPT came up with the following script which runs ok but it has no effect on my sheet at all. Is this on the right track ? Any ideas why it wouldn't ?

```
function setDropdownsToUnassigned() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][5] == "Open") { // Assuming Column F is column 6 (0-based index)
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue("Unassigned"); // Set value in Column G
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Tim

Comment: I tested the script ChatGPT churned out and it works fine, which leads me to believe that the issue's with the data ranges captured by the script. Would you be able to share a sample sheet showing your current input and expected output in order for the community to look into and replicate this? Thank you

Comment: Thanks DuuEyn , I just got it to work too and jumped back to say please ignore....but you wre in so fast ! Thank you. I'm such a newb that I was pasting the code below the 'myFunction" line so that was included when I ran it. Edited out then I got an extra syntax bracket at the end which the editor alerted me too. Deleted that and it ran fine. Sorry for taking up your time unnecessarily...

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value == "Open") {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("Unassigned");
  }
}
```